# How to optimize imports in parallel python processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Let us say that I have a python program that processes text json. Using `multiprocessing.Pool`, I'm going to chew through hundreds of thousands of json files; this will usually take several days.

I have two scripts. There is a master.py script that spawns processes. The spawned processes run an outside program and pipe the result to another python script, via `subprocess.run`.

`otherProgram {args} | pipe.py {more args}`

The `master.py` does not directly spawn the `pipe.py` process; that is done by an OS call, so the things that I import into `master.py' are not shared with the imports required by`pipe.py`.

On a 48 node machine, I have run up to 44 threads in parallel (i.e. `multiprocessing.Pool(44, maxtaskperchild = 10)`).

So I have two related questions regarding the import process:

- Is there any way that importing mostly standard libraries, and one custom module with a few helper functions, is going to negatively impact performance, in a way that I might notice?
- If so, is there a way to optimize imports for the `pipe.py` process? Instead of importing `os` and `binascii` and `tarfile` hundreds of thousands of times, is there some way to make the same set of imports available to multiple processes?

Comment: Can you import everything in the parent and then just `fork` the processes from there so they share the same memory space?

Comment: @Chrispresso I don't really see how to do that, since my `pipe.py` is designed to be run on piped data from `stdout`. At least, I'm not aware of how to make it work that way. This is sort of a design weakness of the code I inherited. This wasn't originally designed to be parallelized (what is?).

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with an executable script (`import_stuff.py`) that had the same imports as the `pipe.py` in question.

```
import subprocess, multiprocessing, datetime

def proc():
   subprocess.run(['/path/to/import_stuff.py', shell = True])
then = datetime.datetime.now()

for _ in range(1000):
   p.appy_async(proc)

p.close()
p.join()

delta = datetime.datetime.now() - then
print(delta)
```

- For 1000 iterations: `0:00:00.665622`
- For 10000 iterations: `0:00:05.981406`
- For 100000 iteration: `0:01:10.125345`

Since 100,000 iterations of my program takes hours to run, the overhead of repeatedly importing things is not very significant.